# MCE7 how to get video from livetv buffer

Tags: windows-7, video, windows-media-center

I'm watching something on my MCE and I can jump back to see something. How can I (if at all) extract a piece of that video that is recorded on my drive somewhere?

If I press record it starts recording from now and past live buffer is lost. Is there a plugin that can do this?

Answer (score 0):

What I did on my Windows MC was rewind to the beginning of the buffer, then hit Record.

As for extracting part of the video, you'll need to use a MCE recorder program to unencrypt and convert